# How to append row in DataTable?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to append more values the rows of a DataTable. The original data read from database doesn't have two additional columns I'd like to add. I've got this so far -

```
myTable.Columns.Add("type", typeof(int));
myTable.Columns.Add("rate", typeof(int));

foreach (DataRow rows in myTable.Rows)
{
    if (rows["dst"] == "1875")
    { 
        //How to append values to this current row?
    }
}
```

Please advice.

Comment: Your question title is asking about appending rows, which is adding *new* rows to the table. Your question text seems to more about adding columns and then data to the *existing* rows. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

```
foreach (DataRow rows in myTable.Rows)
{
    if (rows["dst"] == "1875")
    { 
        //How to append values to this current row?
        rows["type"] = 32;
        rows["rate"] = 64;
    }
}
```

Also as a best practice - change rows in your for loop to row.  It should be singular as it represents a single object - not a collection.

Comment: one little addition, you should make sure that you add  `rows.AcceptChanges();`

Comment: Mark - Correct me if I am wrong but I believe you only have to do that if you are tracking row state.  If you are just displaying data based on the table in a UI you don't need to call accept changes.

Comment: I always assume that there is a backing object involved that I am also updating. I do also check row state. You are correct in this instance.